# Открытие стороннего приложения в диалоге, возможно ли такое сделать?

Tags: android, android-fragment, dialogfragment

Появилась идея открывать в dialogе или в fragmentDialog браузер с перебросом в строку поиска адреса. Есть ли какая-то возможность такое сделать, а то я честно говоря погуглил и пока не нашел ничего стоящего. Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: @danilshik, вы имеете в виду открывать браузер из приложения?

Comment: а вы хотите прям в диалоге его отобразить?

Comment: ну если такое возможно то да, чтобы диалог был как контейнер

Comment: Думаю наврятли такое возможно сделать, если только webview засунуть в контейнер, не более. Но я не эксперт)

Comment: @danilshik, я тоже думаю что такое невозможно сделать, а вебвью ооочень плохо отображает стр, и так как я не очень большой эксперт, то решил спросить здесь

Comment: А можно узнать зачем, даже если бы было возможно, в своем приложении открывать другое, да и тем более DialigFragment не во весь экран, вроде никаких плюсов.

Comment: @Vennic, нужно убрать переходы между двумя приложениями, если опять таки это возможно

Comment: Ну а как их убрать, вы хоть как для работы вызываете активити другого приложения, ведь отдельно, без запуска приложения само активити не может работать. Как бы точнее сказать, его не получится "вырвать".

Comment: вот я об этом и интересуюсь, можно ли результат интента отобразить в диалоге, я лично думал что это невозможно но решил удостоверится